# Android Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger2

Привет всем. Использую в своем проекте фреймворк Dagger 2.
У меня единственный AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AppModule.class
        }
)
```

который содержит AppModule, AppModule в свою очередь содержит другие модули.
Использую создание этого компонента в классе Application

```
component = DaggerAppComponent
        .builder()
        .appModule(new AppModule(this))
        .build();
```

То есть создание компонента происходит только в одном классе. Встречал код, где используется создание различных компонентов во фрагментах и активити, используются различные самкомпоненты и скоупы. Объясните пожалуйста, чем плох мой вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант не плох. Он просто базовый. Изначальный, общий для всех компонент `dagger` должен быть в классе `Application`. Далее, основываясь на нём, можно сделать подкомпоненты, которые будут существовать только в отдельных активити/фрагментах. Но и они должны быть прописаны в базовом компоненте.

Т.е. те способы, что вы видели - примеры расширения вашего и частные случаи.